# How to RedirectToAction from within an ActionFilterAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

whats the best way to do a redirect (preferably a redirect to action) from within an ActionFilterAttribute?

I want to be able to pass data into the controller action from within the ActionFilterAttribute as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To redirect, override `OnActionExecuting` and assign a new `RedirectToRouteResult` to `filterContext.Result`:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult( 
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "newActionName" },
                                       { "actionArgument", someData } });
    }
```

To assign data when redirecting, put it into the route, as shown above.